# Why did new files become blocked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-platform, ruby-on-rails-5, google-cloud-storage

For more than a year, I had a working Rails application with uploading files to Google Cloud Storage. Recently, I found that all new files (images) ceased to be displayed on the site.

I didn’t touch anything on Google Cloud Storage - I did not change any access settings.

I had segment-level access enabled for all users for each object. But for new files, for some reason, access is overwritten. I.e access "is not for everyone."

I do not understand how this happened.

When I try to open a new file, I get an error:

> Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to files.mysite.com/uploads/images/51/ar/6h/0dafasdae64590c0.jpg

The code that I am currently using is:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage = :file

  config.permissions = 0o644
  config.directory_permissions = 0o755

  # config.cache_dir = Rails.root.join('tmp')

  config.cache_dir = '/tmp'

  if Rails.env.development?
    config.root = Rails.root.join('public')
    config.asset_host = "#{Settings.app.protocol}#{Settings.app.host}"
  end

  if Rails.env.production?
    config.fog_provider = 'fog/google'
    config.fog_credentials = {
      path_style: true,
      provider: 'Google',
      google_storage_access_key_id: Settings.api.google.storage.access_key,
      google_storage_secret_access_key: Settings.api.google.storage.secret_access_key
    }
    config.fog_directory = Settings.api.google.storage.bucket
    config.storage = :fog
    config.asset_host = "https://#{Settings.api.google.storage.bucket}"
  end
end

module CarrierWave
  module MiniMagick
    def quality(percentage)
      manipulate! do |img|
        img.quality(percentage.to_s)
        img = yield(img) if block_given?
        img
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Could it be the client for GCS was updated and has new defaults? Or the API changed in some way.

Comment: @Kris I didn't update anything in my project - gem was not updated.

Comment: Could you share the piece of code you are using to upload files to Google Cloud Storage? Maybe you were using some settings that may have changed in the API or in the library.

Comment: @bhito https://pastebin.com/raw/MFp4nUpD

Comment: @Colibri There are zero commits, you didn't run bundle update or deploy?

Comment: Is your org policy, or your project ppolicies have changedm especially "domain restriction policy" ?